# Probability question for picking components out of box

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question regarding this problem.

A manufacturer supplies transistors in boxes of 100. A buyer takes a random
sample of 5 transistors and if one or more are faulty he rejects the box, otherwise he
accepts the box.

(a) If there are 10 faulty transistors in the box what is the probability that the buyer
will accept it?

(b) What is the probability that he rejects a box that contains only one faulty
transistor?

I have solved (a): 90/100 * 89/99 * 88/98 * 87/97 * 86/96 = 0.5837

Can anyone help with (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (a) is correct, but it is more easily solved using combinations, and gives a hint for solving the second part, too.

(a) $\;\;\Large\frac{\binom{90}5\binom{10}0}{\binom{100}5}\; \approx 0.5838 $

You should now be able to solve part (b) along similar lines

> $\Large\frac{\binom{99}{4}\cdot\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{100}{5}}$

Comment: I tried solving it using your approach: (90 4) (10 1) / (100 5), and I got 0.3939.
Is your answer the same?

Comment: The answer is 0.33939. I am not sure if it is correct. My textbook gives the answer of 0.05.

Comment: Sorry, saw formula in a hurry. How can you take $\binom{90}{4}$ ? If exactly $1$ is defective, how many are ok ?

Comment: I am confused now. If 1 is defective, then 4 would be fine, because we consider a 5-sample test, so 1+4=5 is my logic. Can you please provide some clarifications including the formula if you have it.

Comment: You need to consider how many good are there to choose from.

Comment: Now I understand, I got 5/100, which is 0.05. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to be of help !